# React Native: Red screen setting up splash screen on android

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, android-studio, mobile

### What I do

I create a new activity called `SplashActivity.java` with android studio, this create two files:

- `android/app/src/main/java/com/myapp/SplashActivity.java`
- `android/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_splash.xml`

I modified my `AndroidManifest.xml` to set this new activity as the initial activity.

### The problem

I run the application normally with the `yarn android` command which is an npm script that executes the following:

`"android": "react-native run-android --variant=devDebug --appIdSuffix dev"`

the application runs normally, without problems in the console but in the emulator a red screen is shown for a few seconds and then the application is rendered normally, and the splash screen is never shown, I don't know if I set up something wrong in the splas screen associated files or if I am missing something to add, this is a red screen. screenshot

[image]

### Splash screen related files

#### android/app/src/main/java/com/myapp/SplashActivity.java

```java
package com.myapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView( R.layout.activity_splash );

        Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

#### android/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_splash.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="@color/yellow"
  tools:context=".SplashActivity" >

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout >
```

#### android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.myapp" >

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

  <application
    android:name=".MainApplication"
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
      android:name=".SplashActivity"
      android:exported="true">
      <intent-filter >
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter >
    </activity>

    <activity
      android:name=".MainActivity"
      android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode"
      android:exported="true"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:launchMode="singleTask"
      android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
  </application >

</manifest >
```

Comment: Does this answers your question?
https://medium.com/@appstud/add-a-splash-screen-to-a-react-native-app-810492e773f9

Comment: @HetaliBhimjiyani thanks for answering, I did almost the same as shown in the article for android, so I don't know what is wrong.